# Repository pattern best practices

Tags: java, design-patterns, android, repository

Which option is better?

In the first case, I use a universal repository that can work with any entities. The methods of this repository have many parameters, such as string queries, table names, entity mappers, etc. Another option is to use for each entity separate repository (which is probably a good practice).

Advantages of the first option

- One class/service for all entities
- You can send any query string and
  perform a complex query

Minuses

- Domain layer knows many details about the repository, for example
  `Cursor` (Android SDK)
- For each request would have to actually write the method in the repository

What do you think?

**Option 1**

Local Service

```
public interface LocalService {
    <T> Observable<List<T>> get(String table, String sql, Func1<Cursor, T> mapper);
    void removeAll(String table, String sql);
    <T> long save(T item, String table, Func1<T, ContentValues> mapper);
    <T> int update(T item, String table, String where, String[] args, Func1<T, ContentValues> mapper);
}
```

LocalServiceImpl

```
public class LocalServiceImpl  implements LocalService {

    BriteDatabase briteDatabase;

    public LocalServiceImpl(BriteDatabase briteDatabase) {
        this.briteDatabase = briteDatabase;
    }

        @Override
        public <T> Observable<List<T>> get(String table, String sql, Func1<Cursor, T> mapper) {
            return briteDatabase.createQuery(table, sql)
                    .mapToList(mapper)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeAll(String table, String sql) {
            briteDatabase.createQuery(table, sql)
                    .subscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public <T> long save(T item, String table, Func1<T, ContentValues> mapper) {
            return briteDatabase.insert(EventItem.TABLE, mapper.call(item));
        }

        @Override
        public <T> int update(T item, String table, String where, String[] args, Func1<T, ContentValues> mapper) {
            return briteDatabase.update(table,
                    mapper.call(item),
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,
                    where,
                    args);
        }    
    }
```

**Option 2**

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository {
           Observable<List<User>> users();
           Observable<User> user(int userId);  
    }
```

UserRepositoryImpl

```
    public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

        BriteDatabase briteDatabase;

        public UserRepositoryImpl(BriteDatabase briteDatabase) {
            this.briteDatabase = briteDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        public Observable<List<User>> users() {
            return briteDatabase.createQuery(User.TABLE, "SELECT * FROM " + User.TABLE)
                    .mapToList(User.MAPPER)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }    

        @Override
        public Observable<User> user(int userId) {
            return briteDatabase.createQuery(User.TABLE, "SELECT * FROM " + User.TABLE + "WHERE userId = " + userId )
                    .mapToList(User.MAPPER)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }    

   }
```

Comment: Just by reading the code samples I would take the second option. It looks clear and I understand it in a second. I would remove the subscribeOn and observeOn from the repository and let the caller decide where he wants to observe/subscribe

Comment: Thank you for your comments, subscribeOn/observeOn really must be removed from the repository.